# ciphersweet - decryptRow: getting error when trying to decrypt row

Tags: php, database, encryption, indexing

I need some help by using the function decryptRow().

```
    <?php
    
      use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Backend\FIPSCrypto;
      use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\KeyProvider\StringProvider;
      use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\CipherSweet;
      use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\BlindIndex;
      use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedField;
      use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow;
    
      /*************************************************************************************************************************
       * GETTING ACCESS TO ENCRYPTED TABLE DATA ROW & ENCRYPT DATA -> encrypted data will be stored via separate SQL-Select
       * EncryptedRow -> for simple encryption of multiple table fields with Blind Indexing, but without Authentication
       * Encryption method -> FIPS 140-2 algorithms
       * KeyProvider -> StringProvider
       * @param $sKey  //You can pass a raw binary string, hex-encoded string, or base64url-encoded string to the StringProvider constructor, provided the decoded key is 256 bits
       * @param $table  //Table identifier
       * @param $fieldName01  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName02  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName03  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName04  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName05  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName01_bidx  //Field identifier -> will hold the blind index cipher
       * @param $fieldName01Value  //Field value -> that will be encrypted into $ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName02Value  //Field value -> that will be encrypted into $ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName03Value  //Field value -> that will be encrypted into $ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName04Value  //Field value -> that will be encrypted into $ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName05Value  //Field value -> that will be encrypted into $ciphertext
       * @param $prepared  //Holds the encrypted field value & blind index
       * @return int
       */
      function encryptDataTableRow($sKey, $table, $fieldName01, $fieldName02, $fieldName03, $fieldName04, $fieldName05, $fieldName01_bidx, $fieldName01Value, $fieldName02Value, $fieldName03Value, $fieldName04Value, $fieldName05Value, &$prepared): int
      {
        try {
          // Use only FIPS 140-2 algorithms
          $fips = new FIPSCrypto();
    
          // Define Key Provider
          $provider = new StringProvider(
          // Example key, chosen randomly, hex-encoded:
            $sKey
          );
    
          // Start Engine
          $engine = new CipherSweet($provider, $fips);
    
          // Define fields which will be encrypted
          $row = (new EncryptedRow($engine, $table))
            ->addTextField($fieldName01)
            ->addTextField($fieldName02)
            ->addTextField($fieldName03)
            ->addTextField($fieldName04)
            ->addTextField($fieldName05);
    
    
          // Add a normal Blind Index on one field:
          $row->addBlindIndex(
            $fieldName01,
            new BlindIndex(
              $fieldName01_bidx,
              [],
              32
            )
          );
    
          // Set Cipher
    
          $prepared = $row->prepareRowForStorage([
            $fieldName01=>$fieldName01Value,
            $fieldName02=>$fieldName02Value,
            $fieldName03=>$fieldName03Value,
            $fieldName04=>$fieldName04Value,
            $fieldName05=>$fieldName05Value
          ]);
    
          return 0;  //function processed without errors
    
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
          echo "Error: " . $ex->getMessage();
    
          return -1;  //function processed with errors
        }
      }
    
    
    
    
    
      /************************************************************************************************************************
       * GETTING ACCESS TO ENCRYPTED TABLE DATA ROW -> decryption will be processed after fetching via separate SQL-Select
       * EncryptedRow -> for simple encryption of multiple table fields with Blind Indexing, but without Authentication
       * Encryption method -> FIPS 140-2 algorithms
       * KeyProvider -> StringProvider
       * @param $sKey  //You can pass a raw binary string, hex-encoded string, or base64url-encoded string to the StringProvider constructor, provided the decoded key is 256 bits
       * @param $table  //Table identifier
       * @param $fieldName01  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName02  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName03  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName04  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName05  //Field identifier -> will hold ciphertext
       * @param $fieldName01_bidx  //Field identifier -> will hold the blind index cipher
       * @param $fieldName01Value  //Field value -> that will be encrypted into $ciphertext
       * @param $row  //Holds access to decryption model
       * @param $indexes  //Holds the encrypted blind index for sql statement
       * @return int
       */
      function getEncryptDataTableRow($sKey, $table, $fieldName01, $fieldName02, $fieldName03, $fieldName04, $fieldName05, $fieldName01_bidx, $fieldName01Value, &$row, &$indexes): int
      {
        try {
          // Use only FIPS 140-2 algorithms
          $fips = new FIPSCrypto();
    
          // Define Key Provider
          $provider = new StringProvider(
          // Example key, chosen randomly, hex-encoded:
            $sKey
          );
    
          // Start Engine
          $engine = new CipherSweet($provider, $fips);
    
          // Define fields which will be decrypted
          $row = (new EncryptedRow($engine, $table))
            ->addTextField($fieldName01)
            ->addTextField($fieldName02)
            ->addTextField($fieldName03)
            ->addTextField($fieldName04)
            ->addTextField($fieldName05);
    
    
          // Add a normal Blind Index on one field:
          $row->addBlindIndex(
            $fieldName01,
            new BlindIndex(
              $fieldName01_bidx,
              [],
              32
            )
          );
    
    
          // Use these values in search queries:
          $indexes = $row->getAllBlindIndexes([$fieldName01 => $fieldName01Value]);
    
          return 0;  //function processed without errors
    
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
          echo "Error: " . $ex->getMessage();
    
          return -1;  //function processed with errors
        }
      }


  // EncryptedRow without Authentication -> encrypt & store
  function testEncryptDataTableRow() {
       
    $sKey = '4e1c44f87b4cdf21808762970b356891db180a9dd9850e7baf2a79ff3ab8a2fc';
    $table = 'test_multi_field_encryption';
    $fieldName01 = 'customer_name';
    $fieldName02 = 'customer_street';
    $fieldName03 = 'customer_post_code';
    $fieldName04 = 'customer_city';
    $fieldName05 = 'customer_country';
    $fieldName01_bidx = 'customer_bidx';
    $fieldName01Value = 'XXXX AG';
    $fieldName02Value = 'Maylacher 7';
    $fieldName03Value = '70131';
    $fieldName04Value = 'Karlsruhe';
    $fieldName05Value = 'Deutschland';

    $customer_id = 1003;


    $ret = encryptDataTableRow($sKey, $table, $fieldName01, $fieldName02, $fieldName03, $fieldName04, $fieldName05, $fieldName01_bidx, $fieldName01Value, $fieldName02Value,  $fieldName03Value, $fieldName04Value, $fieldName05Value, $prepared);

    try {

      $blindindex = $prepared[1][customer_bidx][value];
      $value01 = $prepared[0][customer_name];
      $value02 = $prepared[0][customer_street];
      $value03 = $prepared[0][customer_post_code];
      $value04 = $prepared[0][customer_city];
      $value05 = $prepared[0][customer_country];


      $db = new MySQLi(...);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `test_multi_field_encryption`(`customer_id`, `customer_name`, `customer_street`, `customer_post_code`, `customer_city`, `customer_country`, `customer_bidx`) VALUES ('" . $customer_id . "','" . $value01 . "','" . $value02 . "','" . $value03 . "','" . $value04 . "','" . $value05 . "','" . $blindindex . "')";

      $result = $db->query($sql);

      $db->close();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo "Fehler: " . $ex->getMessage();
      $db->close();
      $ret = -2;  // no db connection
    }
  }


  // EncryptedRow without Authentication -> select & decrypt
  function testDecryptDataTableRow() {

    $sKey = '4e1c44f87b4cdf21808762970b356891db180a9dd9850e7baf2a79ff3ab8a2fc';
    $table = 'test_multi_field_encryption';
    $fieldName01 = 'customer_name';
    $fieldName02 = 'customer_street';
    $fieldName03 = 'customer_post_code';
    $fieldName04 = 'customer_city';
    $fieldName05 = 'customer_country';
    $fieldName01_bidx = 'customer_bidx';
    $fieldName01Value = 'XXXX AG';


    $ret = getEncryptDataTableRow($sKey, $table, $fieldName01, $fieldName02, $fieldName03, $fieldName04, $fieldName05, $fieldName01_bidx, $fieldName01Value, $rowP, $indexes);

    try {
      $blindindex = $indexes[customer_bidx][value];


      $db = new MySQLi(...);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `test_multi_field_encryption` WHERE customer_bidx = '" . $blindindex . "'";


      $result = $db->query($sql);
      $row = $result->fetch_row();


      $encyptedRow = $rowP->decryptRow($row);


      $db->close();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo "Fehler: " . $ex->getMessage();
      $db->close();
    }
  }
?>
```

My problem is the code line '$encyptedRow = $rowP->decryptRow($row);'. 
 
There I will get an error msg like: 
'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ParagonIE\ConstantTime\Binary::safeSubstr() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\Users...\vendor\paragonie\ciphersweet\src\Backend\FIPSCrypto.php on line 95 and defined in C:\Users...\vendor\paragonie\constant_time_encoding\src\Binary.php:67
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users...\vendor\paragonie\ciphersweet\src\Backend\FIPSCrypto.php(95): ParagonIE\ConstantTime\Binary::safeSubstr(NULL, 0, 5)
#1 C:\Users...\vendor\paragonie\ciphersweet\src\EncryptedRow.php(334): ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Backend\FIPSCrypto->decrypt(NULL, Object(ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Backend\Key\SymmetricKey))
#2 C:\Users...\partials\cipherTEST.php(94): ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow->decryptRow(Array)
#3 C:\Users...'

Maybe someone could help me there.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. My fault was to get the result of the select statement as an index array via

```
$row = $result->fetch_row();
```

But the function decryptRow needs an associative array with the fieldnames. So the code must be like

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Now function decryptRow will get the fieldnames for processing the code line

```
$plaintext = $backend->decrypt($row[$field], $key);
```

Finally it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is due to `null` being passed to `decrypt()` here: https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet/blob/f73aaea31f743dad8145f344d93503c4d9f950a8/src/EncryptedRow.php#L334 . Either `$row[$field]` contain null, or there's no such element in `$row`.

Inspect it with a debugger, or add some debug statements into your `catch` (e.g. `var_dump($rowP, $row)`), then check if the data contained in `$row` is what you expect it to be. It's also worth checking the list of fields in `$rowP->fieldsToEncrypt`.

Comment: Hi Weirdan, many thanks for your fast answer. 

I got it. My fault was to get the result of the select statement as an index array via

$row = $result->fetch_row();

But the function decryptRow needs an associative array with the fieldnames. So the code must be like

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

Now function decryptRow will get the fieldnames for processing the code line

$plaintext = $backend->decrypt($row[$field], $key);

Finally it works very well. Regards